# MASM locals: dynamically allocated data?

Tags: c++, masm

I'm learning masm32, following some tutorials.
In one tutorial: http://win32assembly.online.fr/tut3.html
there is stated:

> LOCAL directive allocates memory from the stack for local variables
>   used in the function. The bunch of LOCAL directives must be
>   immediately below the PROC directive. The LOCAL directive is
>   immediately followed by :.
>   So LOCAL wc:WNDCLASSEX tells MASM to allocate memory from the stack
>   the size of WNDCLASSEX structure for the variable named wc. We can
>   refer to wc in our codes without any difficulty involved in stack
>   manipulation. That's really a godsend, I think. The downside  is that
>   local variables cannot be used outside the function they're created
>   and will be automatically destroyed when the function returns to the
>   caller. Another drawback is that you cannot initialize local variables
>   automatically because **they're just stack memory allocated dynamically**
>   when the function is entered . You have to manually assign them with
>   desired values after LOCAL directives.

I've always been told stack memory is static, and any dynamic allocation is heap.
Can we really consider those as locals in the sense of C++ then?
When you create local variables in C++, will those variables be dynamically allocated on the stack as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we really consider those as locals in the sense of C++ then? When you create local variables in C++, will those variables be dynamically allocated on the stack as well?

In C++, local (automatic) variables live on the stack, so yes and yes.

They are allocated dynamically in the sense that they come and go as the function is entered/exited. However, as you rightly point out, this type of allocation is rather different from heap allocation.

In addition to the heap and the stack, there is a third area where variables can reside. It is the data segment. It's where global as well as function- and class-level `static` variables live.

Comment: is data segment memory like the upper most level of the stack (for your program)? Or is it something completely different. Just taking a wild guess

Comment: @xcrypt: That is to some extent OS-specific. For a generic high-level view, see http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/14268

Comment: @xcrypt: For another writeup, see http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory